# Amazon EC2 Apache Symbolic Link Not Allowed

Tags: linux, apache, permissions, symlink, vhosts

I have created an Amazon EC2 instance and installed Apache and PHP on it:

```
$ sudo yum install apache2
$ sudo yum install php
$ ls -al /var/www/services/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   42 Jun 22 21:13 production -> /home/ec2-user/services
```

The I have created new VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ec2-***.compute-1.amazonaws.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/services/production/public"

    <Directory "/var/www/services/production/public">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, when I run my request in the browser, it says `403 Forbidden` and the log shows symlink problem:

```
[Wed Jun 22 21:14:19 2011] [error] [client ***] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/services/production
[Wed Jun 22 21:14:20 2011] [error] [client ***] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www/services/production
```

What's wrong? Is EC2 blocking symlinks? Please help!

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATED**

Now, the only problem I could think of is `permission` to access `production` by `apache` user. Make sure the permission to `/var/www/services/production` (& the **target** folder) folder is set to `0755` on both **symbolic links & target folder**.

Test:
Become the user as apache (`sudo -u apache`) and now try to change into the directory (`cd`) and make sure `apache` user is able to traverse.

Comment: It's a Zend Framework application, so your concern is noted, but it's not answering my question. Thank you!

Comment: @Eistrati can you try the above suggested `conf`

Comment: Yes, I did and same issue, as expected. This has nothing to do with VirtualHost config. I assume it's either (less probably) I am missing something in Apache2's general config `httpd.conf` or (most probably) I need to do some changes in OS configs. That's why I asked specifically about Amazon EC2... Does this make sense?

Answer (score 2):

Does Apache have read permissions on /home/ec2-user/services? Symlinks are by design 0777 for permissions, but only so everything flows through to take up the permissions of whatever the symlink is pointing at.

Comment: Yes, it does. I have chown'ed everything to apache group.